# SQL Server - insert large number of rows?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

*I've read many answers here about this topic, but everyone suggests the <kbd>BCP</kbd> || <kbd>SqlBulkCopy</kbd> class from .net*

I have a query which inserts into `targetTable` the *union* of 5 `selects` from different tables.

I have correct indexes on the tables being selected. And only 1 clustered identity index on the `targetTable`. However this takes a long time (~25 min). I'm talking about 5M rows (x 20 columns).

When I look at <kbd>sp_who2</kbd>, most of the time, it is `suspended`...

I want to use `bulk` copy but *not* from .net (the db already fetches the data - so I don't need to go to C#).

**Questions**

- How can I use bulk insert (no bcp) in my select command?
- Also, why is it suspended most of time? How can I give my query a higher *priority*?

Thank you.

*p.s. I can't use `bcp` here because of security restrictions... I don't have permission to run this.*

Comment: Have you considered using the `Export data wizard' in SQL server? You can also save it as a SSIS package and use it later when needed. It supports specifying a custom query for the source data.

Comment: @thecoon the command to begin this whole process comes from a button at a web page....which starts the sp which starts fetching data to the target table... so I don't think Its implementable here

Comment: You could try out the coon's suggestion while running Sql Profiler to see how its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right: This is taking longer than usual. You're getting 3k rows per second. You should get 10k or 20k per second easily. In the best case 200k per second per CPU core

I suspect you are inserting all over the table, not just at the end. In this case, 3k rows per second is not unusual.

**In any case, bulk copy cannot help you.** It does not insert faster than a server-only insert statement.

What you can do, though, is insert using multiple threads. Partition your row source into N distinct ranges and insert each range concurrently from a separate connection. This will help if you are CPU bound. It won't if you are IO bound.

Comment: what do you mean _inserting all over the table_ ?

Comment: At random positions, not at the end.

Comment: its a normal table with id identity seeed  1,1. how can it be not at the end ?

Comment: Hm in this case I don't know why it is that slow for you. You'd need to post more code and the execution plan of the insert statement as a screenshot. Maybe I can spot some problem.